# python IO: Splitting words from textfile into python array, avoiding escaping chars, newlines, hexvalues

Tags: python, arrays, string, io, split

I'm having a hard time importing and splitting words properly from a simple txt-file into a python array.

Txtfile:

```
test1 file test1 test1 
test2 test2 
test 3 test3, test3.

test 4, test 4.


test 5


^Ltest 6.
```

When doing a simple `for lines in file: array.append(lines)`
this is the final array i recieve:

```
['test1 file test1 test1\xc2\xa0\n', 'test2 test2\xc2\xa0\n', 'test 3 test3, test3.\n', '\n', 'test 4, test 4.\n', '\n', '\n', 'test 5\n', '\n', '\n', '^Ltest 6.\xc2\xa0\n']
```

I'd like it to be something like this, where i have one item per actual english word or escaping character, and without the \x__ hex substrings:

```
['test1', 'file', 'test1', 'test1', '\n', 'test2', 'test2', '\n', 'test', '3', 'test3', 'test3', '.', '\n', '\n', 'test', '4', 'test', '4', '.', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'test', '5', '\n', '\n', '\n', 'test 6', '.', \n']
```

Help would be really appreciated, thanks beforehand.

Comment: `[w for w in file.read().split() if re.match(r'[\w\n\.]+$',w)]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Could you please be a little specific on how you'd interpret this? 're.match' gives me compilation-errors. \w means the regex [a-zA-Z0-9_]?

Comment: yes. did you run `import re`?

Comment: Hi. I got it to work as i interpreted it as this, thanks alot. It works for the testfile shown above, but not for a bigger txt-file, 
`worddata = []
datafile = open('test.txt','r')
worddata.append([w for w in datafile.read().split() if re.match(r'[\w\n\.]+$',w)])`
For a bigger txt file, it returns an empty array inside an array: [[]], do you have an idea why that may be?

Comment: I'm so sorry, i made a mistake with utf-8 encoding. All works now, thanks alot! Is there a way of rewarding your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single line solution:

```
[w for w in file.read().split() if re.match(r'[\w\n\.]+$',w)]
```

For parsing large file, it's better to pre-compile the regex.

```
import re
word_ptn = re.compile(r'[\w\n\.]+$')
[w for w in file.read().split() if word_ptn.match(w)]
```

The above regex will filter out strings like `'test1\xc2\xa0\n'`. If you want to keep it, extract the matched string from the regex results:

```
word_ptn = re.compile(r'[\w\n\.]+')
Lp = (word_ptn.match(w) for w in file.read().split())
[ w.group(0) for w in Lp if w ]
```